# How to decrease size of image when we decrease the browser size.?

Tags: html, css

I have inserted an image through css. When I decrease the size of browser window the size of image remains same so how to decrease size image.

I coded like following:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <br/>
    <div id="slideshow">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS as follows:

```
#slideshow{
    background:url(img/image.png) no-repeat;
    height:512px;
    /*margin:auto 30px;*/
    margin:40px 28px auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

I did Google very much. But i am not getting how to resolve this issue.
Please can any one help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use **%** insted of **px**.

Comment: When I make in #slideshow.. height:auto; then image vanishes..

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looking for changing an image, you are looking for changing a **background**, which is very different.

You could use `background-size` to make the background resizable when the element change. Some posible values:

```
background-size: cover;
background-size: contain;
background-size: 100%;
background-size: 200px 300px;
```

I usually use *cover* or *contain*, both fits image to its container, in different ways. Try it out.

More info about **background-size**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 1):

use CSS background property to scale the image

```
#slideshow {
background-size:cover;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#slideshow{
    background:url(res/iphone_small.png) no-repeat;
    height:50%;
    /*margin:auto 30px;*/
    margin:40px 28px auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This will not change the background size of the element.